# How to scroll RecyclerView item beyond the boundaries

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to scroll item beyond the boundaries.
I have attached image for reference.

Please help.

[image: photo]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by not making the `RecyclerView` a child of the view that draws the white background.  Simply make them both children of a parent that is the full width of the screen, with the RecyclerView on top.  That way the RecyclerView will scroll the full width of the screen, and the background will, separately, be drawn where you want it.